Show lines in scratch buffer in preview window
I am looking for a way to create a new scratch buffer from given lines of text and show the result in a preview window (as done by :pedit).
I think I have a handle on creating the buffer, but I am unsure how I can make it show up in the preview window. Any help is appreciated!
" show in preview window
function! Preview(lines)
    let l:buf = bufadd('')
    call setbufvar(l:buf, '&buftype', 'nofile')
    call setbufvar(l:buf, '&buflisted', 0)
    call setbufvar(l:buf, '&swapfile', 0)
    call setbufvar(l:buf, '&number', 0)
    call bufload(l:buf)
    call setbufline(l:buf, 1, a:lines)
    call setbufvar(l:buf, '&modifiable', 0)
    " execute 'silent! pedit! ... ???'
endfunction


I would do:
function! LoadPreviewWindow(bufnr)
  try
    wincmd P
  catch
    silent! pedit!
    wincmd P
  endtry
  execute 'b' . a:bufnr
  wincmd p
endfunction

" show in preview window
function! Preview(lines)
    let l:buf = bufadd('')
    call setbufvar(l:buf, '&buftype', 'nofile')
    call setbufvar(l:buf, '&buflisted', 0)
    call setbufvar(l:buf, '&swapfile', 0)
    call setbufvar(l:buf, '&number', 0)
    call bufload(l:buf)
    call setbufline(l:buf, 1, a:lines)
    call setbufvar(l:buf, '&modifiable', 0)
    " execute 'silent! pedit!
    LoadPreviewWindow(l:buf)
endfunction

The LoadPreviewWindow function create the preview window if not already present and change the buffer loaded in the preview window

Excellent, thank you!

Welcome to Vim! Thanks for the feedback :-)
